# Generating all possible combinations of n-sized vector that follow certain conditions on each element

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have a list d of length r such that  `d = (d_1, d_2,..., d_r)`. 
I would like to generate all possible vectors of length r such that `for any i (from 0 to r), v_i is between 0 and d_i`.

For example,

```
if r =2 and d= (1,2), v_1 can be 0 or 1 and v_2 can be 0,1 or 2.
```

Hence there are 6 possible vectors:
             `[0,0] , [0,1], [0,2], [1,0] , [1,1], [1,2]`

I have looked into Itertools and combinations and I have a feeling I will have to use recursion however I have not managed to solve it yet and was hoping for some help or advice into the right direction.

Edit:
I have written the following code for my problem and **it works** however I did it in a very inefficient way by disregarding the condition and generating all possible vectors then pruning the invalid ones. I took the largest `d_i` and generated all vectors of size `r` from `(0,0,...0)` all the way to `(max_d_i,max_d_i,....max_d_i)` and then eliminated those that were invalid.

Code:

```
import itertools
import copy
def main(d):
    arr = []
    correct_list =[]
    curr = []
    r= len(d)
    greatest = max(d)
    for i in range(0,greatest+1):
        arr = arr + [i]
    #all_poss_arr is a list that holds all possible vectors of length r from (0,0,...,0) to (max,max,...,max)
    # for example if greatest was 3 and r= 4, all_poss_arr would have (0,0,0,0), then (0,0,0,1) and so on,
    #all the way to (3,3,3,3)
    all_poss_arr = list(itertools.product(arr,repeat = r))    
    #Now I am going to remove all the vectors that dont follow the v_i is between 0 and d_i
    for i in range(0,len(all_poss_arr)):
        curr = all_poss_arr[i]
        cnt = 0
        for j in range(0,len(curr)):
            if curr[j] <= d[j]:
                cnt = cnt +1
        if cnt == r:
            curr = list(curr)
            currcopy = copy.copy(curr)
            correct_list = correct_list + [currcopy]
            cnt =0
    return correct_list
```

If anyone knows a better way, let me know, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Comment: @MartinBackasch I went through many posts regarding generating all possible combinations and I have yet to find one that has different restrictions/conditions on each element of the vector they are trying to generate.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I am still working on it and send it shortly. Thank you

Comment: @GabrielDeza: You could take a look at the code of [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) or [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) to get an idea if you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @MartinBackasch I just edited the post with my own solution. I used itertools.products and I purposely generated all possible vectors and then eliminated the invalid ones. Although it works, I feel like there is a way to not generate all of them and apply the condition during generation and not after.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want a Cartesian product.  I'll demonstrate a basic, functional and iterative approach.

**Given**

```
import operator as op
import functools as ft
import itertools as it


def compose(f, g):
    """Return a function composed of two functions."""
    def h(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(g(*args, **kwargs))
    return h


d = (1, 2)
```

**Code**

*Option 1: Basic - Manual Unpacking*

```
list(it.product(range(d[0] + 1), range(d[1] + 1)))
# [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

*Option 2: Functional - Automated Mapping*

```
def vector_combs(v):
    """Return a Cartesian product of unpacked elements from `v`."""
    plus_one = ft.partial(op.add, 1)
    range_plus_one = compose(range, plus_one)
    res = list(it.product(*map(range_plus_one, v)))
    return res


vector_combs(d)
# [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

*Option 3: Iterative - Range Replication (Recommended)*

```
list(it.product(*[range(x + 1) for x in d]))
# [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

---

**Details**

*Option 1*

The basic idea is illustrated in Option 1:

- Make a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) using a series of modified ranges.

Note, each range is *manually incremented* and *passed in* as an index from `d`.  We automate these limitations in with the last options.

*Option 2*

We apply a functional approach to handle the various arguments and functions:

- [Partial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) the `1` argument to the `add()` function.  This returns a function that will increment any number.
- Let's pass this function into `range` through [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)).  This allows us to have a modified range function that auto increments the integer passed in.
- Finally we [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) the latter function to each element in tuple `d`.  Now `d` works with any length `r`.

Example (`d = (1, 2, 1), r = 3`):

```
vector_combs((1, 2, 1))
# [(0, 0, 0),
#  (0, 0, 1),
#  (0, 1, 0),
#  (0, 1, 1),
#  (0, 2, 0),
#  (0, 2, 1),
#  (1, 0, 0),
#  (1, 0, 1),
#  (1, 1, 0),
#  (1, 1, 1),
#  (1, 2, 0),
#  (1, 2, 1)]
```

*Option 3*

Perhaps most elegantly, just use a list comprehension to create `r` ranges. ;)

Comment: Wow! I can't believe my 15+ lines of code was reduced to 1 line of code in option 3. Thank you so much for the different options and their explanation! I am a little bit stunned how all 3 of your solutions are so much nicer than mine :)

Comment: Understanding the core problem is often the first step.   Take however many lines you need.  One-liners aren't necessarily the "nicest" solutions, but Pythonic ones are.   You are likely seeing the intrinsic effect of how elegant Python is as a language.  Almost always, there's a Pythonic way out there.  Just keep coding.